# Query records between two dates duration

Tags: android, sqlite, date, android-sqlite

So I simply have `start_time`, `end_time` and `duration` columns in a table. And I want to query the data between 2 dates. (start_time and end_time are in epoch millis)

So, for example dates are **2016-12-05** to **2016-12-08**. So, for this I also need to include the records which starts on **2016-12-04** but ends on between **2016-12-05**  and starts on **2016-12-08** and ends **on 2016-12-09**. And all records in between those dates.

I am unable to come up with the combination of WHERE clause which will query the exact data.

One part I can get is like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table 
    WHERE 
         date(datetime(start_time/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) >= '2016-12-05' 
    AND 
         date(datetime(start_time/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) <= '2012-12-08'
```

But this won't include all the records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic seems to imply that if either the start or the end falls within the range, then it should be considered a match.  If so, then the following query should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table 
WHERE 
(
    date(datetime(start_time/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) >= '2016-12-05' AND
    date(datetime(start_time/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) <= '2012-12-08'
) OR
(
    date(datetime(end_time/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) >= '2016-12-05' AND
    date(datetime(end_time/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) <= '2012-12-08'
)
```

Comment: It looks like it will include all the records between 2 given dates

Comment: And that whats I want. I'll just check this out

Comment: @kirtan403 The logic includes dates falling between.  These dates have _both_ start and end dates inside the range, but only one condition is required.

Comment: What I am getting is, all the records are sequential. Means, after 1 session completed, the next session will always have the start_time greater than the last record's end_time. There won't be any overlaps. So currently this seems right to me.

Comment: @kirtan403 Let us know if you need any further help.

Comment: I am just testing this out. Sure. thank you so much :) .  Will accept the answer after I test on my test data.